# Trying to store multiple values in db, but my form only registers one(via checkboxes)

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I hope my title isnt too vague. I am working on a project to store objects with different genres in a database. The database consists of two tables, one for the objects and one for the different genres. Everything works fine, except that my html form doesnt seem to be able to store multiple genres via checkboxes. When I check multiple boxes when using the form, only the last one checked gets stored.

I can store multiple genres on one object  executing SQL manually via Workbench, but the form doesnt seem to send the right stuff. I am definetly doing something wrong. Someone out there that can help out? Thanks in advance.

Here is the function for generating the form:

```
/**
 * Content creation form
**/
public function formCreateObjectContent($output){

    $sql = '
        SELECT * 
        FROM `Genre` 
    ';
    $res = $this->db->ExecuteSelectQueryAndFetchAll($sql);           

    $html="
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <div id='object-edit'>
            <form method='post'>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Create new object</legend>

                <p><label>Title:<br/><input type='text' name='title' required/></label></p>

                <p><label>Cover-image:<br/><input type='text' name='image' value='default.png'/></label></p>

                <ul>";
                foreach($res as $val) {
                    $html .= "<li><input type='checkbox' name='genre' value='{$val->id}'/>$val->name</li>";
                }         
                $html .= "</ul> 

                <p><label>Start Date:<br/><input type='text' name='start_date' value='0000-00-00'/></label></p>

                <p><label>End Date:<br/><input type='text' name='end_date' value='0000-00-00'/></label></p>

                <p><input type='submit' name='save' value='Save'/> <input type='reset' value='Reset'/></p>

                <output><p>{$output}</p></output>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    ";

    return $html; 
}
```

And here is the function for the SQL:

```
/**
 * Create content
**/
public function createObjectContent($title, $genre, $image, $start_date, $end_date, $created, $save){
$output = null;

if($save) {

  // Insert content to database.
  $sql = '
    INSERT INTO `Object` (`title`, `image`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `created`) VALUES
    (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())
  ';      
  $params = array($title, $image, $start_date, $end_date);
  $res = $this->db->ExecuteQuery($sql, $params);

  if($res) {
    // Get id of the created Object.
    $sql2 = '
      SELECT * 
      FROM `Object`
      ORDER BY `created` DESC
      LIMIT 1;
    ';
    $params2 = array();
    $res2 = $this->db->ExecuteSelectQueryAndFetchAll($sql2, $params2);

    foreach($res2 AS $val){
      $idObject = $val->id;
    }

    // Match object id with genre id.
    $sql = '
      INSERT INTO `Object2Genre` (`idObject`, `idGenre`)
      VALUES (?, ?);
    '
    ;
    $url = empty($url) ? null : $url;
    $params = array($idObject, $genre);
    $res = $this->db->ExecuteQuery($sql, $params);  
  }

  // Return result.
  if ($res){
    $output = header('Location:browse.php');
  }

  else {
    $output = "<p>Object could not be created.</p>" . print_r($this->db->ErrorInfo(), 1) . '</pre>';
  }
}
return $output;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter your HTML code and add [] to the checkbox names:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Java"><label>Java</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php
if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    //to run PHP script on submit
    if( !empty($_POST['check_list']) )
    {
        // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected)
        {
            echo $selected."</br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

(As per http://www.formget.com/php-checkbox/)

Comment: Now I'm getting an error:

Object could not be created.Array ( [0] => 23000 [1] => 1452 [2] => Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ymer`.`object2genre`, CONSTRAINT `object2genre_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`idGenre`) REFERENCES `genre` (`id`)) )

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the right method, thank you. I guess I'll have to create another question to deal with the errors.